# Getting MD5 with certain character pattern

Tags: hash, md5

I'm using the first 6 characters of an MD5 hashed string to use for displaying a color.

ie:

```
"hello world".Md5().Substring(0, 6);
```

There is a certain instance in my application where I need a certain color. I want to feed data that I know will provide a certain character pattern (in my case FF0000).

So is there a way to.. reverse generate an MD5? Or a good way of brute building MD5s to produce an MD5 hash that starts out in FF0000?

If this is impossible, I can hardcoded this exception into the application, however the least amount of "hacks" required, the better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reverse an MD5 as it's a one way function. But we can try candidates until we find one that we like.

Here is a small program that increments a counter and test that counter as a string for md5 hash.
It takes a few seconds and 2 million tries to find an md5 starting with FF0000.

Python 3:

```
import hashlib

target = 'ff0000'
candidate = 0
while True:
    plaintext = str(candidate)
    hash = hashlib.md5(plaintext.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
    if hash[:6] == target:
        print('plaintext:"' + plaintext + '", md5:' + hash)
        break
    candidate = candidate + 1
```

Result:

```
plaintext:"2237563", md5:ff0000475d94089c1f6c3fb9e19a8015
```

Comment: Straight forward enough. I was afraid a brute force was going to take ages. Thanks!